would have / would have had

#1 You wouldn't have so many accidents if you drove more carefully.

I think it's about present state, but the accidents happened in the past. So, I think it's not right.

#2 You wouldn't have had so many accidents if you drove more carefully.

I think it's right.
But, the website says #1
What do you think about this? #1 are possible to use?

It depends entirely on what you want to say. It's potentially confusing for non-Anglophones that the verb to have appears in both versions (only as "unmarked infinitive" in #1, but also forming the Present Perfect in #2). If you're specifically talking about accidents the addressee has already had (in the Past), use Present Perfect as in #2. Where despite the form of the name, Present Perfect refers to the Past (that has special relevance to the Present).  If you're talking about Past, Present and Future accidents, use Simple Present as in #1.

...that's to say, if you know the person you're talking to no longer drives, and is never going to drive in the future, you could only use format #2. In that situation, format #1 just wouldn't make sense. Note that some pedants will suggest you should use ...if you had driven more carefully in #2. But in most contexts - well, they're pedants. Simplest is usually best. And I'd have to say any website that endorses one format over the other without specifying the context is a complete waste of time (or worse, actively misleading). Avoid it.

Thank you so much, It really helped!. And could you let me know some website or text book I can learn from context? I feel learning English without context can be very dangerous.

Just read actual text written by native Anglophones, and forget about "teaching aids" which on the Internet at large are often very low quality. There must be subjects and types of narrative stories you find interesting, so just look for texts that don't immediately strike you as very difficult to understand (for example, you might find a book by Hemingway or JK Rowling easier to understand than one by Dickens or Jane Austen). Don't assume that by "stretching" yourself with more challenging texts you'll learn faster or better. It's the precise opposite when you think how we natives learned.

Also search on Youtube and similar sites to find clear-spoken native Anglophones talking about things that interest you (possibly with subtitles; even auto-generated subtitles are very accurate today if you stick to people who speak clearly). And don't obsess about trying to fully understand every single word. That's not how people learn their own native language, and it's usually quite okay to "defer" understanding some particular element of written or spoken text until it either becomes better understood OR you forget it because it wasn't all that important in the first place.

#1 is easier to say

As the comments have explained, this demonstrates the difference between a simple present conditional (#1) and a present perfect conditional (#2). #1 is grammatically correct, and the sentence would be advice to drive more carefully in general. It explains a relationship between driving carefully and having fewer accidents that is not about a specific time.

You (generally) would have fewer accidents if you were (generally) more careful.

Or, to use another example:

You wouldn't be so tired if you went to bed earlier. (source)

While the sentence is about the past, it implies you should do something in the future (In the examples, being more careful and going to bed earlier). #2, however, refers specifically to past events. They way you wrote it was actually grammatically incorrect. The second verb should be in the past perfect tense, like this:

You wouldn't have had so many accidents if you had driven more carefully.

The events have already completed, and the sentence is more of a "what if" something happened, rather than a general relationship. We can see the difference between #1 and #2 more clearly by slightly altering the sentence:

You wouldn't crash so often if you drove more carefully. (Crashing is an event that has happened in the past and may happen again)


You wouldn't have crashed into that building if you had driven more carefully. (This specific crash is an event that has already happened and will not happen again)

So, in conclusion, #1 is grammatically consistent with the other verb and refers to generic statements. #2, when grammatically correct, refers to specific conditionals relating to events that have already completed.

The simple present can be used make generalizations even when the generalization is based on a pattern of past behavior.

You are a reckless driver.

Or

You wouldn't have so many accidents if ...

which could be paraphrased "You would be involved in fewer accidents  if ..."
In other words, you would be a safer driver in general if ...

... if you drove more carefully.

There is a backshift to the past tense there to mark the counterfactual. You do not drive carefully.  It could be stated also with a modal:

if you would drive more carefully.

